# Pinned-icon State

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, css

Ok, so you know the whole deal with Pinned sites in IE9 and 10, right? And you can add teeny weeny little icons to the Jump-List on the task bar...

Have (not there anymore) you seen the Facebook taskbar icon change when you get a new Notification? In the taskbar, it changes from the normal "f" logo, to the "f" logo with a number (representing number of new notifications) on top of the "f" logo.

How can we change (or swap) Taskbar icons to convey to the user a new notification?

I've spent the last few hours going over the docs for pinned sites at MSDN but I can't see any references for that particular feature.

Has anybody had any experience with this? Or do you know of any resources you may have seen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called "Icon overlays".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg491744(v=vs.85).aspx#create

Googled for: pinned sites ie notification

Also, check out this jQuery plugin which wraps a lot of this for you: http://ie9ify.codeplex.com/

Comment: OVERLAYS! Yes! That's the word I was trying to remember, but all that kept coming to mind was "facebook-like notification thingy". Thank you!

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure "facebook-like notification thingy" was Microsoft's working name for that feature. ;)